# Stream follows the apple's standards for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, streaming

I have a stream URL that I load in my application.However i am not quite sure whether the stream follows apple requirements.Is there any way I could be certain.
Here is the URL

http://ms.mta.tv:8081/stm.m3u8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mediastreamvalidator

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2235/_index.html

Comment: After running it by myself, all you got were mostly warnings, but a couple of errors too. Seems that some segments are missing. Correct it and you should be ready to go :)